# Erro na comparação entre um EditText e um String

Tags: java, android, string, comparação, edittext

Estou tentando comparar o texto inserido em uma EditText com um item da minha ArrayList, porém a condição nunca é verdadeira.

```
int aux=-1;

for (int i = 0; i < lista2.size(); i++) {
    if (edContato.getText().equals(lista2.get(i))){
        aux = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (rbExcluir.isChecked()) {
    if(aux>=0){
        principal();
        lista2.remove(aux);
        aplicarLista();
    }
    else {
        dialogo.setTitle("Erro!");
        dialogo.setMessage("Contato não encontrado!");
        dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        dialogo.show();
        excluir_alterar();
    }
```

Sou iniciante em programação para Android e até onde eu sei, no Java essa comparação funcionaria. Estou deixando alguma coisa passar? Essa situação requer algum outro método de comparação?

Answer (score 3):

Você está a comparar um [Editable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) com um String.

O objecto retornado pelo método [EditText#getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) é do tipo Editable.

Para obter a string no EditText tem de usar o método `toString()` do Editable.

Em vez de

```
edContato.getText().equals(lista2.get(i))
```

use

```
edContato.getText().toString().equals(lista2.get(i))
```

Comment: Tentei isso e não funcionou. Ele continua não entrando na condição.

Comment: Então é porque a lista2 não tem nenhum item igual ao conteúdo do EditText.

Comment: Eu coloquei no meio do código um AlertDialog que me retorna os dois valores, apenas para fins de teste, e os dois conteúdos são aparentemente idênticos. Tentei até converter tanto o EditText quanto o item da lista para string e ainda assim a condição continua falsa.

Comment: De que tipo é o ArrayList?

Comment: Não defini um tipo ao declarar o ArrayList. Estou fazendo o seguinte: tenho um ListView (lista) para mostrar os dados inseridos no ArrayList (lista2) com o auxílio de um ArrayAdapter (adp) do tipo String. Seria essa a sua pergunta?

Comment: Que tipo de objecto está a guardar no ArrayList? São Strings?

Comment: Eu pego o conteúdo de um EditText e adiciono no ArrayList:

lista2.add(editText1.getText());

Comment: Encontrei o erro! Converti o conteúdo do EditText para String antes de adicionar à lista e agora estou conseguindo remover os itens. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sempre que declarar um ArrayList indique o tipo que ele vai receber: `ArrayList<String> lista2;`. Se o tivesse feito o compilador teria avisado que havia um erro quando você usou `lista2.add(editText1.getText());`